# how to run res.render() only when the instructions written above is executed first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the below code i want to fininsh the completion of for loop first then after res.render()  should run(i mean synchrounously ) but here res.render() function runs before completion of the for loop.....
However if i use **setTimeout(function(){res.render("checkout",{user:req.user,cartItems:cartItems,sum:sum})},1500);** it works but i am doing it forcefully because the above for loop completes before the 1500 milliseconds so then the correct items will be rendered in the front end side. Please help me.... I just want to run it just after my all task gets over.
.
.
.
.
.

```js
app.get("/profile/checkout", function(req, res) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        var cartItems=[];
        var sum=0;
        if(req.user.cart.length >= 1) {
            for(let eachItems of req.user.cart) {
                Product.findOne({_id: eachItems.product_id}, function(err, foundData) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else {
                        sum = sum + foundData.price;
                        var obj = {
                            cart_item_id: eachItems._id,
                            product_id: foundData._id,
                            brand: foundData.brand,
                            title: foundData.title,
                            price: foundData.price,
                            image: foundData.image,
                            selected_size: eachItems.selected_size
                        };
                        cartItems.push(obj);
                        console.log(cartItems);
                     }
                });
            }
            res.render("checkout", {
                user: req.user, 
                cartItems: cartItems, 
                sum: sum
            });
        } else {
            res.render("checkout", {user: req.user});
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect("/home/login");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using `Promise.all`. This will wait until the loop is over and all promises are resolved before going on to the response. (there may be a syntax error somewhere I didn't test it):

```
app.get("/profile/checkout",async function(req,res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    var sum=0;
    if(req.user.cart.length>=1){
        
      const cartItems = await Promise.all( req.user.cart.map( async ( eachItem ) => {
        const foundData = await Product.findOne({_id:eachItems.product_id})

        sum += foundData.price;

        var obj={
          cart_item_id:eachItems._id,
          product_id:foundData._id,
          brand:foundData.brand,
          title:foundData.title,
          price:foundData.price,
          image:foundData.image,
          selected_size:eachItems.selected_size
        };

        return Promise.resolve( obj )
      } )

      res.render("checkout",{user:req.user, cartItems, sum});

    }else{
      res.render("checkout",{user:req.user});
    }
  else {
    res.redirect("/home/login");
  }
});
```